# Best Practice for Automatically Setting Name Field on Object with Trigger

Tags: visualforce, trigger

I plan on setting the Name field on an object automatically.  I will be using a trigger Before Update/Insert to concatenate a few fields into the Name field.  The problem is that, by default, SalesForce requires a Name to be input when a record is created.

[image: Required Name Field]

Obviously I can just allow the user to enter a Name which I would then overwrite, but that seems a little janky to me.  **Does anyone know of a better way to go about this without creating a VisualForce page to manage the initial record creation?**  There are up to 50 fields that need to be input and I'd rather not maintain that in a VisualForce page.

I attempted to just make the field an AutoNumber, but that also makes the field Read-only.

Comment: I know you want to avoid VF Page, but if you use a Visualforce Page and use Field Sets you will get flexibility of VF Page with configuration ability of Page Layouts. Yes it is a bit more maintenance work but that is the standard way I solve this for most implementations. Plus if you do this in a VF Page you do not risk technical debt that triggers and Workflow Rules can incure since they operate at Data layer and fire on all DML points (API Integrations, VF Pages, Salesforce 1 Saves, etc)

Comment: @CoryCowgill It kind of seems like that is the route I will have to go.  One thing that I didn't consider is that I don't necessarily have to have every single field on the Creation VisualForce page.  I can just include fields that are required or helpful.

Comment: Yes. And use a Field Set for the love of all that is holy. That will allow you to change order / what fields are displayed on the VF Page without doing code or deployments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to set a default name based on the Parent object(you would need to customize the button and url hack to do it. ) and then have the trigger change it out. Is there any reason you wouldn't want to just use a workflow rule instead of going the trigger route?

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be the standard Name field? I would suggest to just create a custom field and use that and just hide the Name field in the page layout.

Comment: I suppose that could work.  I could make the custom name field searchable.  The only thing that I'm not crazy about is how the name field must be shown on Related Lists meaning that users will still primarily have to interact with the generated AutoNumber.

Comment: If you need it in autonumber then just copy the standard name value and set it to the custom field value after insert event trigger or through a workflow